# can't change color of actionBar divider

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-actionbar

I tried change color of my actionBar divider , but nothing work. I' using android support library v7 for support old devices and custom style, and i also change all action bar drawable, but nothing happend!

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent = "Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@drawable/my_action_bar</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And my ide show me strange error in layout , why did i get this error? it's not color value

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Color value '@drawable/abs__ab_transparent_dark_holo' must start with #
```

Solution: Need to add android namespace if use for api level >= 14 .May be it will be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the "divider" is an image. It's hardcoded in the Holo theme assets.

Look at platforms/android-19/data/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ab_transparent_dark_holo.9.png

The style is declared here for holo dark.

```
<style name="Widget.Holo.ActionBar" parent="Widget.ActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/ab_transparent_dark_holo</item>
        ...
</style>
```

It's a background. You will need to change the color in the image and replace the background of your bar.
It also needs different sizes for different resolutions.

Comment: This code works . I'm already learned why my code doesn't work - i need to add android namespace if use for api level >= 14

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should set color directly, change your theme as

```
<item name="android:divider">@color/dividercolor</item>
```

Then you should add color dividercolor in you /value/color file,like

```
<item name="dividercolor"> #0099CC </item>
```

Comment: your solution change full color of action bar

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake...I have changed the code. It should be android:divider instead of android:background.

Comment: Alternatively, if you keep the background stuff, just apply the theme to divider instead of the whole actionbar.

Comment: also doesn't work for me , maybe it's because of an exception? how can i fix this?

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will be helpful to you

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@drawable/action_vertical_doted</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.ActionButton</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#ffffff</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyTheme.Menu.FontStyle</item> -->
    <!-- <item name="android:actionBarSize">50dp</item> -->

</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_bg_shap</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">none</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/actionbar_bg_shap</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.ActionButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/main_button_inactive_tr</item>
</style>
```