# Dividers for the actionbar menu items

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am developing Tablet android application. Here i got one issue with the UI of the action bar menu items.

Note: I am using android Native actionbar.

1) How to show divider between menu items like as show in the image. [image] 
I tried with divider styles and custom styles but it doesn`t reflect in my action bar.

2) How can I add multiple menu items into a single menu item like as show in the picture. 
[image]

I tried with custom layout but overflow menu for the items is not showing.
I tried with PopupMenu for the overflow menu but the icon is not visible in overflow list.

Here I was using styles for the action bar application, styles.xml

```
    <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.MenuTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/dividercolor</item>

</style>

  <style name="OverFlow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_actionbar_dots</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:height">100dip</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.Text</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/divider</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">beginning</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">10dp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.MenuTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">26sp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

menu.xml

```
<group android:id="@+id/menu_mainGroup" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/connection"
        android:icon="@drawable/nw_pt_calc"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title=" ">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/status_menu"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/application_status_overflowmenu"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText">
    </item>

    <!--
    <item
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_available"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        >
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/status1"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_available"
                android:showAsAction="always"
                android:title="@string/menu_available">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/status2"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_busy"
                android:showAsAction="always"
                android:title="@string/menu_busy">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/status3"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_logoff"
                android:showAsAction="always"
                android:title="@string/menu_logoff">
            </item>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/display_pic"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_person"
        android:showAsAction="always">
    </item>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/display_name"
        android:showAsAction="always">
    </item>


    -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="false">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="false">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/about">
    </item>
    <!--
         <item
        android:id="@+id/notification_history"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/notification_history">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/comm_msg_history"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/comm_msg_history">
    </item>



    -->
</group>
```

Help will be appreciated. Thanks looking forward to hear answers from geeks :).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have resolved your problem. But I can explain you just in case.
First of all, to customize the divider in your `ActionBar`, you must to do this in your `Theme` with the parent `ActionButton`. You do this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:divider">@color/dividercolor</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/divider</item>
</style>
```

Try this way:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="actionBarDivider">@color/blue</item>
</style>  

<style name="ActionButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
   <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

You can read the solution here: [Can't change color of actionBar divider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20597488/2668136) and there: [ActionBar MenuItem Divider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11445488/2668136).

Then, you can create a [`9-Patch`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#NinePatch) drawable to look like exactly at your image. Try to use something like this image:  [image: divider_blue.9.png]
The black border indicate where expand your image. I did it on the left/right sides to expand your divider on its height. You can read [Draw 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) from the Documentation to know how use the `Draw 9-Patch tool` in the sdk.
Or, you can make it in xml, something like below:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <!-- first line vertical blue -->
   <item android:left="1dp">
       <shape android:shape="line">
           <stroke
               android:color="@color/blue"
               android:width="1dp" />
       </shape>
   </item>
   <!-- second line vertical white -->
   <item android:right="1dp">
       <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
               android:color="@color/white"
               android:width="1dp" />
       </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

After that, you just have to declare it in your `style.xml` as:
`<item ...>@drawable/blue_divider</item>`.

Now you have customize divider (=

---

Then, your custom layout in `ActionBar`.
It's possible to do as below:

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
 actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.application_status_overflowmenu);
 actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM|
                                    ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
```

And `application_status_overflowmenu.xml` will be something like:

```
 <RelativeLayout
     android="@+id/theCustomIcon"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="right" android:gravity="center"
     android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
     android:clickable="true" >

     <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/blockCustomIcon"
          android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp"  
          android:src="@drawable/green_block"  
          android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

     <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imgCustomIcon"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
          android:src="@drawable/green_block"  
          android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/blockCustomIcon" />

     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtCustomIcon"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
          android:src="@drawable/green_block"  
          android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:gravity="left" />  

 </RelativeLayout>
```

And finally, you can have access to the `View`s to update the items:

```
 TextView text = (TextView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.txtCustomIcon);
 text.setText("Emily Nichols");
```

That's all!
If your menu options disappears, check if your `onCreateOptionsMenu` is inflating a good layout and if it return true. You can also add the custom item in front of options menu or add item dynamically. I let you do this as you want.
I hope this will be useful and it will helpful too.